# Why are there no previous versions of my Word files on box.com?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word-2013, box.com

I am working with Word 2013 and box.com. Whenever I save a new version from inside Word, I also do a file save as PDF to view the output as PDF. I can recover all my PDF files from box.com but from the Word file there is only one version available. Does anyone know why saving from inside Word does not produce new versions on box.com and how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what information you have given, here is what is happening.

Word does not produce a new file each time you save. When you save, it overwrites the existing file with the changes you have made since the last save. That is just how Word works.

The reason you have those PDF versions is because you saved them that way;  you said "*I also do a file save as PDF to view the output as PDF*". Word did not do it automatically.

To do as you desire, use the `File > Save As` with the Word document like you do with the PDF files.

Comment: I would also assume the author is overwriting the existing PDF file, if all they are doing is, saving as a PDF it would have the same filename each time.  I suspect the cloud service itself simply does not keep versions of Word documents for whatever reason.

Comment: @Ramhound That is true unless the user is manually renaming them for the sake of revision control (but we lack those details here). Using "save as" sometimes confuses people because when the action is done, the open document is now the one just saved, not the one previously worked on.

Comment: The lack of details is one reason I voted to migrated.  I suspect box.com simply does not do file revisions, on files uploaded to it.

Comment: @CharlieRB: I am not renaming the Word file each time. It keeps getting the same filename, i use Ctrl-S to save. I do not do a "Save as" so I am working on the current document. Is using "Save as" the solution for this problem?

Comment: @Ramhound: box.com does file revisions, I can show you a screenshot.

Comment: @gentlesea - You indicate you do use the "save as" option since you create a PDF file.  Box.com might do file revisions for other formats but it clearly does not do it for Word documents.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yeah, that is what I noticed. But why is that and how can I fix that? There is an option "Upload new version" in the web interface. This way I can also have file revisions on Word files. But I want that to happen automatically. Otherwise I would have to do a "Save as" to another place, change from Word to Chrome, find the file and do a "Upload new version". Ufff...

Comment: @gentlesea - Contact Box.com support for an answer to those questions.

Comment: @gentlesea Yes. using `Save As` will help you with revision control. You asked 'why' in your question, but I added a solution to my answer anyway.